# Textfield focus on tab key press not working properly in IE for ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

I am testing my Reactjs app having two textfields (one below the other) on Internet Explorer 10. When I press tab from the first textfield, ideally it should set focus on the next textfield (which is what it is doing in chrome and firefox) but actually I need to press the tab key twice to set focus on the second field.

```
 <TextBox
   email
 />
  <TextBox
    password
  />
```

Here `<TextBox>` is the component created by me which internally uses `<Input>` .

Kindly suggest any possible solutions to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the markup? It is possible that there's something else created and IE focuses on that before. You could also intercept the 'keypress' event and directly focus on the next textarea.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the generated markup (HTML), so we can see if there's a reason why the focus stop somewhere else in between.